# Set value of an unknown Django Model Field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am implementing a function that gets a model class as a parameter, and should get a dictionary from the same model, set model fields to namesake keys in such dictionary, and save the model to the database.

This is the code of the function:

```
def populate_model(self, model_to_populate):
    model_to_populate_instance = model_to_populate()

    if hasattr(model_to_populate_instance, 'populate_data'):
        populate_data = getattr(model_to_populate, 'populate_data')
        for key, value in populate_data.items():
            field = getattr(model_to_populate_instance, key)
            field = value

            model_to_populate_instance.save()
```

Something is wrong because I don't get values from the dictionary in the database, but objects `GeneralApp.models.CustomCharField>`. I guess I am not succeeding to set the value of the model instance field to the value in the dictionary.

O would appreciate your help.

Comment: why is the data a field called `populate_data`?

Comment: @e4c5 it is not a field, it is a dictionary attribute with some information that must be populated to the database table related to the model

Comment: @HugoLuisVillalobosCanto What you mean by *"and should get a dictionary from the same model"* ?

Comment: @Jerin Peter George, that the model received as a parameter has a dictionary attribute that must be accessed (`populate_data = getattr(model_to_populate, 'populate_data')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the lines

```
        field = getattr(model_to_populate_instance, key)
        field = value
```

with

```
        setattr(model_to_populate_instance, key, value)
```

Reason: the return value of `getattr` is the *value* of the attribute, not a reference to the attribute itself (if it were a reference, it wouldn't make sense to set `field = value` anyway.